# Adding a column and award scheme to a list box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two text box's Txtmark and TxtName that data is entered in then stored in an array after 20 entries a list box is displayed to show the name and mark what i want to do id add an extra column that has awards

High Distinction 90% and above; 
Distinction 75% up to 89%; 
Credit 60% up to 74%; and 
Pass 50% up to 59%, 
everything else is particpation

this is the code i have so far:

```
    'Enter scores - press  to place value into Array
Private Sub TxtMark_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtMark.KeyPress


    Dim Mark As Double
    Dim DataString As String

    If e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Cr Then

        If Double.TryParse(TxtMark.Text, Mark) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show(" You must enter a numeric value like 1 or 2")
            TxtMark.Clear()
            TxtMark.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Mark < 0 Or Mark > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Valid range is between 0 and 100, 7 would work " _
                & Mark.ToString & " Does not")
            TxtMark.Clear()
            TxtMark.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If



        If NumberOfScores < MaxEntries Then
            ScoreArray(NumberOfScores) = Mark

            DataString = (NumberOfScores + 1).ToString + ".  " + _
                NameArray(NumberOfScores).PadRight(15) + _
  Mark.ToString.PadLeft(5)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DataString)
            NumberOfScores += 1
        End If
        TxtMark.Clear()
        TxtName.Clear()
        TxtName.Focus()
        Exit Sub

    End If


    If ListBox1.Items.Count >= 20 Then
        ListBox1.Visible = True
    Else
        ListBox1.Visible = False
    End If
```

Comment: Is it an assignment? Please clarify your question!

Comment: Yes this is an assignment  i need to add an extra column in the listbox that shows the "award" e.g if bary got 67 then his award would be a credit does that help

Comment: Try using punctuation. It'll make it easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since listbox doesn't have any actual columns, what you really mean is adding on to your datastring so the information appears columnized

Add a function to convert the mark to the award something like this:

```
Private Function NewAward(Mark As Double) As String
    Select Case Mark
        Case 90 To 100
            Return "High Distinction"
        Case 75 To 89
            Return "Distinction"
        Case 60 To 74
            Return "Credit"
        Case 50 To 59
            Return "Pass"
        Case Else
            Return "Participation"
    End Select
End Function
```

Then make your DataString like this:

```
DataString = (NumberOfScores + 1).ToString + ".  " + _
                NameArray(NumberOfScores).PadRight(15) + _
  Mark.ToString.PadLeft(5) + " - " + NewAward(Mark)
```

UPDATE:

To add the awards from a button click instead:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For I = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim TempString As String = ListBox1.Items(I).ToString
        Dim Mark As Double = Double.Parse(TempString.Substring(TempString.Length - 5))
        TempString += " - " + NewAward(Mark)
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(I)
        ListBox1.Items.Insert(I, TempString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how you could have the awards only added when a button is pressed

Comment: load the listbox without the awards.  Then in the click event handler of the button, iterate through the listbox items(use For instead of For Each), extract the mark(ListBox.Items(I).Substring(ListBox.Items(I).Length-5)).  Since the ListBox.Items collection is ReadOnly, you'll have to save the item to a temporary variable and add the award, Remove the item then Insert the modified variable.  The listbox should display the awards.

Comment: I am no sure how to do this

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. One more thing is there a way if i press the button again the grades will disappear, then if its pressed again they will re appear etc.

Comment: You can use a class level boolean(`Dim ShowGrades As Boolean = True`).  Then in the Click event handler,use an If statement to check if it's False to remove the grades.  Then change the boolean for the next button click('ShowGrades = Not ShowGrades').